# Automatic bounty not awarded to an accepted answer

Tags: bug, bounties, accepted-answer, expired-bounty

According to the current [bounty documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) (*November 2020*):

> #### How is a bounty awarded?
>
> ...
>
> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period),
> **the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a**
> **minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full**
> **amount, if the answer is also accepted)**. If two or more eligible
> answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer
> is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is
> awarded to anyone.

my accepted answer in this question ["React Native ImageBackground Orientation Change"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64397404/react-native-imagebackground-orientation-change) should have been awarded the bounty but it did not.

As you can see in the [revisions log](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64397404/revisions) the bounty **started by the question author** at `Oct 28 03:23` **2 minutes after accepting my answer** at `Oct 28 03:21`.

And today **after the grace period has ended**, the system did not automatically awared any of the bounty, **not even the half (200 out off 400 bounty) on a 6 times upvoted answer** with the message *"Bounty Ended with no winning answer by Community♦"*.

I've got automatic bounties in the past and I know it's working, so, I'd like to know what I'm missing here and what case did this Q/A hit and didn't get any bounty automatically awarded.

Comment: the automatic bounty awarding is for answers posted _after_ the bounty started.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What about the half of the bounty on the highest (and minimum of 2 upvotes) upvoted answer? My A got 6 upvotes, shouldn't it get the half of the bounty according to the current rules?

Comment: You didn't pickup enough upvotes on the first bounty to be awarded. For the second bounty your answer wasn't eligible because it was posted before the  second bounty started. The OP had to award the bounty to you but they failed to do so.

Comment: Not a bug: The bounty was placed **after** you posted your answer. Only answers that have been posted after the bounty are eligible.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, it's all clear to me now. Should I close this or leave it open?